# laravel database error when I try to convert an string to datetime

Tags: php, laravel, database, datetime

I'm on Laravel project that I didn't start, my problem is when I try to do an insert on laravel.

I need to insert a datetime, on Y-m-d h:i:s.v format but when i do the call

```
"date" => DB::raw('convert(datetime,GETDATE(),21)')
```

Insert returns

```
13-05-2022 15:14:29
```

That's not the format I need and don't know if the error come from laravel because when I do the same statement on DB it runs.

```
select convert(datetime,GETDATE(),21)
```

returns 2022-05-13 17:13:41.267

Thanks for your time.

Comment: An insert doesn't return anything, not sure what you mean. Regardless, a raw clause is executed exactly the same way as it's typed. Check your database query logs and see what's actually being sent.

Comment: On my laravel version was not executing exactly what I was saying I dont know why. When I said insert returns i mean that I was returning insert result, I think that is not so hard to understand what was the question. I dont think that I must to say you every single step and code that im writing, try to use your reading skills

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem changing datatype on DB, changing `datetime` type to `date`.

Is not the first time that I had problems with `datetime` type so I suggest that don't use it.

Comment: Glad you got it working, but plenty of systems run just fine using the `datetime` datatype; blanket recommending not to use it with no evidence supporting why, aside from your personal issue using it is kinda silly.